# Display result matching optgroup using select2

Tags: jquery-select2, optgroup

I'm using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) with Bootstrap 3.
Now I would like to know whether it is possible to display all optgroup items if the search matches the optgroup name while still being able to search for items as well. If this is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually found the solution by modifying the matcher opt

```
 $("#myselect").select2({
    matcher: function(term, text, opt){
         return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0 || opt.parent("optgroup").attr("label").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0
    }
});
```

Under the premise that the label attribute has been set in each optgroup.

Comment: Nice! I recommend using the default matcher implementation, though, unless you intentionally want to deviate from the default matcher. `element.select2({ matcher: function (term, text, opt) { return element.select2.defaults.matcher(term, text) || element.select2.defaults.matcher(term, opt.parent("optgroup").attr("label")); } });` This allows for slightly better matching by not only ignoring case, but also ignoring diacritics.

Comment: text.toUpperCase is not a function error. Debugged and saw that text comes as object, not string? Have you seen this problem?

Comment: No not seen. What kind of object is that? Do you have a dump of the object? Perhabs with newer version the matcher params have been changed?

Comment: Select2 V4 passes different params to the matcher function. (See answer from @willbradley) Maybe that could help you

Answer (score 32):

The above answers don't seem to work out of the box with Select2 4.0 so if you're hunting for that, check this out: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3034

(Use the function like this: `$("#example").select2({matcher: modelMatcher});`)

```
function modelMatcher (params, data) {
  data.parentText = data.parentText || "";

  // Always return the object if there is nothing to compare
  if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
    return data;
  }

  // Do a recursive check for options with children
  if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
    // Clone the data object if there are children
    // This is required as we modify the object to remove any non-matches
    var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);

    // Check each child of the option
    for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
      var child = data.children[c];
      child.parentText += data.parentText + " " + data.text;

      var matches = modelMatcher(params, child);

      // If there wasn't a match, remove the object in the array
      if (matches == null) {
        match.children.splice(c, 1);
      }
    }

    // If any children matched, return the new object
    if (match.children.length > 0) {
      return match;
    }

    // If there were no matching children, check just the plain object
    return modelMatcher(params, match);
  }

  // If the typed-in term matches the text of this term, or the text from any
  // parent term, then it's a match.
  var original = (data.parentText + ' ' + data.text).toUpperCase();
  var term = params.term.toUpperCase();


  // Check if the text contains the term
  if (original.indexOf(term) > -1) {
    return data;
  }

  // If it doesn't contain the term, don't return anything
  return null;
}
```

Comment: this worked. this should now be the answer, as the above indeed have issues. thanks willbradley.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution from [select2/issues/3034](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3034#issuecomment-961003240)

Tested with select2 v.4

```js
$("select").select2({
    matcher(params, data) {
        const originalMatcher = $.fn.select2.defaults.defaults.matcher;
        const result = originalMatcher(params, data);

        if (
            result &&
            data.children &&
            result.children &&
            data.children.length
        ) {
            if (
                data.children.length !== result.children.length &&
                data.text.toLowerCase().includes(params.term.toLowerCase())
            ) {
                result.children = data.children;
            }
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few minor changes to people suggested code, less repetitive and copes when there are no parent optgroups:

```
$('select').select2({
    matcher: function(term, text, opt){
        var matcher = opt.parent('select').select2.defaults.matcher;                        
        return matcher(term, text) || (opt.parent('optgroup').length && matcher(term, opt.parent('optgroup').attr("label"))); 
    }
});
```